# Value of schma registry with protobufs

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

I am using protobufs with kafka based microservices now and I am wondering what the real benefits of using the schema registry with protobufs are when one needs to code generate interfaces from the original schema and hence need a copy of the schema when deploying the service?

I totally get it for avro / json schema etc where one doesn't need the schema ahead of time but with protobufs, the schema registry doesn't seem to add any value.

Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> need a copy of the schema when deploying the service

Where do you get the copy? Hopefully not copied between random projects. How do you know what schema is the latest, as you make changes? How do you know if any changes are compatible with previous schemas, as you make them?

The Schema Registry is a centralized location for collecting schemas (consumers shouldn't need deployed with a copy of the schema file, if they don't want to; the producer can generate the models, upload them to Artifactory, for example, then consumers should use those as a dependency, not recompile from the schema), that also offers compatibility checks between versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @OneCricketeer.  As a follow-up on "consumers shouldn't need deployed with a copy of the schema file", can you point me to any example where one  doesn't need to "recompile from the schema".  This is the core of my confusion as in every case I have seen, one needs to run `protoc` generator ahead of time on the consumer. If the consumer could use the schema from the SR, I totally see the benefits. Thanks again.

Comment: @robcxyz Like I said, the Producers should be able to produce an dependency with the compiled classes that can be uploaded to an artifact repository, such as Artifactory, then the consumers can download that dependency without needing to use protoc again. That has nothing to do with the schema registry